# I would like to calculate the difference between two floats datatypes and hours within respective columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the difference between enrollment fees that were paid within 24 hours and is less than 10000 USD each but when combined is greater than 10000 USD that was paid by specific/unqiue students

See below for columns/data dictionary in my dataset for clarity

- **Student ID (string dataype):** This is a unique ID that is specific to each student, for students that enrolled in more than more course, they will appear in multiply rows under the same ID
- **Enrollment Date (datetime datatype) :** The is the date of enrollment for different courses
- **Enrollment Time (datetime dataype) :** This is the time of enrollment for the different courses
- **Enrollment Fees (Float datatype):** This is amount paid to enroll in a course

I firstly want to identify students that enrolled in more than one course using the count method as in my notebook but I don't know where to go from here.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your 'student_information' table and added some rows for the sake of this answer.

```
import pandas as pd
#Converted your table from the image you provide to excel.
student_information = pd.read_excel('/content/student_data_notebook picture.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
student_information.head(10)
```

| index | enrollment_date | enrollment_time_number | enrolment_fees | student_id | enrollment_time | total_fee_difference_24_hours | total_fee_difference_24_hours_over_10000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 28000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 18:37:23 | true | true |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 10000 | 2456977 | 1970-01-02 18:37:23 | false | false |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 132351 | 23690 | 3182054 | 1970-01-02 12:45:51 | false | false |
| 3 | 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | 154452 | 20000 | 3193091 | 1970-01-02 18:54:12 | false | false |
| 4 | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | 134746 | 33436 | 2911297 | 1970-01-02 13:25:46 | false | false |
| 5 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 18000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 21:37:23 | true | true |
| 6 | 2019-08-03 00:00:00 | 153443 | 31000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 23:37:23 | true | true |
| 7 | 2019-08-04 00:00:00 | 153443 | 45000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 13:37:23 | true | true |
| 8 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 10000 | 2456977 | 1970-01-05 18:37:23 | false | false |
| 9 | 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | 153443 | 25000 | 2456977 | 1970-01-08 18:38:23 | false | false |

```
#Checked the data type of each column.
student_information.dtypes
```

enrollment_date           datetime64[ns]
enrollment_time_number             int64
enrolment_fees                     int64
student_id                         int64
enrollment_time           datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

```
#Created a summary table to add to the number of enrolled courses for each student.
student_summary = student_information.groupby('student_id')['enrolment_fees'].count().reset_index()
student_summary.rename(columns={'enrolment_fees': 'number_of_enrolled_courses'}, inplace = True)
student_summary
```

| index | student_id | number_of_enrolled_courses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2286141 | 4 |
| 1 | 2456977 | 3 |
| 2 | 2911297 | 1 |
| 3 | 3182054 | 1 |
| 4 | 3193091 | 1 |

```
#Added the total fees paid for each student id and a column to check if its over 100000.
student_summary['total_fees'] = student_information.groupby('student_id')['enrolment_fees'].sum().reset_index()['enrolment_fees']
student_summary['over_100000_in_fees'] = student_summary['total_fees'] > 100000
student_summary
```

| index | student_id | number_of_enrolled_courses | total_fees | over_100000_in_fees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2286141 | 4 | 122000 | true |
| 1 | 2456977 | 3 | 45000 | false |
| 2 | 2911297 | 1 | 33436 | false |
| 3 | 3182054 | 1 | 23690 | false |
| 4 | 3193091 | 1 | 20000 | false |

```
'''
A column is added to the 'student_information' table to represent the difference in fees within 24 hours for each student, relative to each course they are enrolled in and if the sum is smaller than 10000.
''' 
length_df = student_information.shape[0]
list_total_fee_difference = []
for row in range(length_df):
    student_id = student_information.iloc[row]['student_id']
    enrollment_time = student_information.iloc[row]['enrollment_time']
    enrollment_fees = student_information.iloc[row]['enrolment_fees']
    low_time_limit = enrollment_time - pd.Timedelta('1 Day')
    upper_time_limit = enrollment_time + pd.Timedelta('1 Day')
    total_fee_difference = 0
    for row_2 in range(length_df):
        enrollment_time_2 = student_information.iloc[row_2]['enrollment_time']
        student_id_2 = enrollment_time = student_information.iloc[row_2]['student_id']
        enrollment_fees_2 = student_information.iloc[row_2]['enrolment_fees']
        if ((student_id == student_id_2) and 
            (enrollment_time_2 >= low_time_limit) and 
            (upper_time_limit >= enrollment_time_2)):
            total_fee_difference += abs(enrollment_fees - enrollment_fees_2)
    list_total_fee_difference.append(total_fee_difference)
series_total_fee_difference = pd.Series(list_total_fee_difference)
student_information['total_fee_difference_24_hours_over_10000'] = series_total_fee_difference.values > 10000
student_information
```

| index | enrollment_date | enrollment_time_number | enrolment_fees | student_id | enrollment_time | total_fee_difference_24_hours_under_10000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 28000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 18:37:23 | false |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 10000 | 2456977 | 1970-01-02 18:37:23 | true |
| 2 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 132351 | 23690 | 3182054 | 1970-01-02 12:45:51 | true |
| 3 | 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | 154452 | 20000 | 3193091 | 1970-01-02 18:54:12 | true |
| 4 | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | 134746 | 33436 | 2911297 | 1970-01-02 13:25:46 | true |
| 5 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 18000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 21:37:23 | false |
| 6 | 2019-08-03 00:00:00 | 153443 | 31000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 23:37:23 | false |
| 7 | 2019-08-04 00:00:00 | 153443 | 45000 | 2286141 | 1970-01-02 13:37:23 | false |
| 8 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | 153443 | 10000 | 2456977 | 1970-01-05 18:37:23 | true |
| 9 | 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | 153443 | 25000 | 2456977 | 1970-01-08 18:38:23 | true |

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting this together, I am trying to understand the codes line by Line and I will let you know when/if I need additional questions

Comment: Can you please explain what this line of code does? ---- enrollment_time = student_information.iloc[row]['enrollment_time'].

Comment: The following line: 'enrollment_time = student_information.iloc[row]['enrollment_time']' is used to store the enrollment time at a given row index. The 'student_information' table has rows that have indices from '0' to '9' by using 'iloc' rows can be selected using these position-based integers. The 'row' inside of the brackets represents an integer generated by the range in the loop used to dedicate which row is addressed. However, we want the 'enrollment_time' not the full row so we need to specify the column we want which is ['enrollment_time'] to obtain enrollment time at a given row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, it's very clear and easy to understand. Can you also explain the following lines of code.low_time_limit = enrollment_time - pd.Timedelta('1 Day')
    upper_time_limit = enrollment_time + pd.Timedelta('1 Day')
    total_fee_difference = 0

Comment: In the following lines: 'low_time_limit = enrollment_time - pd.Timedelta('1 Day')
    upper_time_limit = enrollment_time + pd.Timedelta('1 Day')
    total_fee_difference = 0'
The 'Timedelta' method is used as an operator to modify a 'datetime64' data type and the upper/lower limits set the range to make sure selected dates are within a 24-hour range. Also, prior to the nested loop, the difference between times is always reset to zero.

Comment: can I please meet with you to better understand this code, If it's fine with you I can schedule a zoom session.

Comment: DM me on twitter.